# MySql count all rows in table which are before the current month and current year

Tags: mysql, date

I have rows in xyz table in which each record having a column **dated** and one column that is **is_decided** which holds 1 or 0.

My Problem is that i want to get all the rows which has is_decided = 1 and the dated column must have one month before from the current month.

for this i used the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(sno) AS total 
FROM xyz
WHERE 
dated > DATE_SUB('2016-02-01',INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND 
is_decided = 1
```

here in the query the hard coded date is the current date from mysql database. (NOW()).

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I need all record according to the query which should qualify the condition and all the record must be surely before from the current month.

**EDIT**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz
--------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
`sno` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dated` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT 'fixed date to this fir for hearing',
`is_current` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'current record',
`is_decided` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=not decided  1=decided',
`date_entry` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT 'entry of this record',
 PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What is the result of running your query?

Comment: It return 5 as result while the table have only 3 records which should be displayed. two records having 2016-02-08, 2016-02-15 and other three records having 2016-01-29,

Comment: Is the first of the month the cutoff? Your query as it currently is written will return all records whose date is greater than `2016-01-01` and `is_decided = 1`

Comment: @Rob M- Does Greater than means here all the old records than the current month? if yes, then i really need it, but my query is not returning the proper records. My question is simple, i need to return all records which has older than the current month and is_decided = 1 thats all

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DATEADD()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp).

```
SELECT COUNT(sno) AS total 
FROM xyz
WHERE DATE_ADD(dated,1 MONTH) < NOW()
AND is_decided = 1
```

Comment: dated > NOW() will be true if there is any record match from yesterday? is it not?

Comment: @AbdulRahman I edited my answer. Is that solving your problem?

Comment: I am using MySql 5.7 and it return error with your query i have checked with date_add() but still no luck

Comment: I have already converted your query and tested as you wrote here but it returns 0 records.

Comment: it's data type is "date"

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd = 2016-02-20